# How can I return a true or false from a method in one return line?

Tags: java

How can I rewrite this method so it uses only one return statement and no other lines?

```
public boolean contains(String key) {
    if (search(key) == null)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Replace if with `return search(key) != null`'

Comment: Look for 'ternary operator' in [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

Comment: @mcalex He doesnt need to use the ternary operator. Since he is just checking on a boolean value, he can just return that.

Comment: True.  Still worth knowing about.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`Objects.isNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#isNull-java.lang.Object-) here:

```java
public boolean contains (String key) {
    return !Objects.isNull(search(key));
}
```

Comment: Why not remove the `!` and use `nonNull`?

Answer (score 2):

you can simply return `(search(key)!= null)`

```
public boolean contains( String key ){
  return (search(key)!= null);   
}
```